Automation of date selector in android simulator
I am trying to automate the process where i have to select date as input string.


When i try to identify the page source, this calendar is itself not loading in html.
HTML of this input field looks like
<input dir="auto" data-bloks-name="bk.components.TextInput" 
aria-label="Date of birth (0 year old)" max="3024-01-05" 
class="wbloks_1 wbloks_74" placeholder="" type="date" value="2024-09-03" 
style="background: transparent; color: rgb(28, 43, 51); font-family: &quot;Optimistic Text Medium&quot;; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.3;">

I have tried sending keys as
dob_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Date of birth (0 year old)']"))
        )
dob_input.clear()
dob_input.send_keys("1994-01-21")

It doesnt work.
I have tried javascript
dob_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Date of birth (0 year old)']"))
        )
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]", dob_input, "2000-09-03")

It doesnt work.
